# selenium not finding the element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a textbox and enter text in it through selenium web driver. The html is as follows:

```
</div><div>
    <input name="mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$Database" type="text" value="Enter database name" maxlength="175" size="26" id="mLayout_ctl00_ctl00_6_16_ctl00_Database" accesskey="s" title="Go search this database" class="InputContent GhostText" onfocus="SearchBoxOnFocus(&#39;mLayout_ctl00_ctl00_6_16_ctl00_Database&#39;);" onkeypress="if(!__TextBoxOnKeyPress(&#39;mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$GoButton&#39;,event.which)) { return false; }" />&nbsp;<input type="image" name="mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$GoButton" id="mLayout_ctl00_ctl00_6_16_ctl00_GoButton" title="Go search database" src="http://images-statcont.westlaw.com/images/go_v602.gif" alt="Go search database" align="absmiddle" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$GoButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="height:18px;width:21px;border-width:0px;" />
</div><div>
```

I've tried the following

```
driver.find_element_by_id("mLayout_ctl00_ctl00_6_16_ctl00_Database")
driver.find_element_by_name("mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$Database")
dbElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda x : x.find_element_by_id("mLayout_ctl00_ctl00_6_16_ctl00_Database"))
```

Is there something special about the $ and _ characters is the fields? Why can't selenium locate these elements?

Comment: Similar: [Selenium-Python find_element_by_link_text - unable to locate element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18023678/55075)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution: make sure you are in the right window. In the step before this one, I had clicked on a link that opened a new window, and I had assumed that that window would automatically be the active one.

To see which windows are available, run:

```
driver.window_handles
```

This returns a list. Note the window you want to change to, with index i. To then change the window, run:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional double inverted commas in your second line, after `find_element_by_name(""`

```
driver.find_element_by_name(""mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$Database")
```

Change it to

```
driver.find_element_by_name("mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$Database")
```

and whenever not sure abt the `$` and `_` then use single inverted commas, something like this

```
driver.find_element_by_name('mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$Database')
```

Comment: This still results in the same error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"mLayout$ctl00$ctl00$6$16$ctl00$Database"}'

Comment: did u try with the single inverted commas??

Comment: is the element actually present on the page? is the name of the element dynamically created? I cant imagine any reason why someone would actually name a text field that.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is in following. IF you are not able to located element by the whole name I would try to locate it by the part of the name.
So i would try this approach:

Attribute A of element  where A contains 't'

**xpath**:
//E[contains(@A,'t')]/@A ⌦ {Se: `//E[contains(@A,'t')]@A` }

**css**: 
NA {Se: `css=E[A*='t']@A` }
taken [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/)

So it be something

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("input[contains(@name,'ctl00$Database')]@name")
```

in that way i usually verify in cases I'm not confident about my locator:
[image]

Comment: Would it be something like this: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name,'ctl00$Database')]")

I still get an error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@name,\'ctl00$Database\')]"}'

Comment: how about simple "driver.find_element_by_xpath("input[contains(@name,'Database')" ?

don't forget to verify found locator of the element in firepath, firebug addon in ffox